# laravel eloquent mark objects with relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

```
class PaymentMethod extends Model
{
     ....

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
    ...
}

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    ...

    public function payment_methods()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PaymentMethod::class, $this->getForeignKey())->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }

    public function default_payment_method()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(PaymentMethod::class, 'id', 'default_payment_method_id');
    }


    ...
}
```

In the views

```
@if($user -> getDefautPaymentMethod()->type == PaymentMethod::PAYPAL_ACCOUNT)
    <div><strong>Paypal: </strong> {{$user -> getDefautPaymentMethod()-> paypal_email}}</div>
@else
    <div><strong>Card: </strong>{{$user -> getDefautPaymentMethod()-> card_brand}} **** **** **** {{$user -> getDefautPaymentMethod()-> card_last_four}}</div>
@endif
```

This work fine. And outputs default payment method for user.

But i want't output all payments method for user. And for each method output label if this is default for user.

I don't want't DB::RAW or sub queries in cicle

```
    @foreach($user->payment_methods()->get() as $payment_method)
        @if($payment_method ->type == PaymentMethod::PAYPAL_ACCOUNT)
            <div><strong>Paypal: </strong> {{$payment_method -> paypal_email}}</div>
        @else
            <div><strong>Card: </strong>{{ $payment_method -> card_brand }} **** **** **** {{$payment_method -> card_last_four}}</div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
```

How affect this cicle and model code for output if method default?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the payment methods, and compare the ID's with the default payment method's ID. They can match, you know it's the default.

```
@foreach ($user->payment-methods()->get() as $payment_method)
    <div>
        @if ($user->get_default_payment_method()->id === $payment_method->id)
            <strong>Default Payment Method</strong>
        @endif
        {{ $payment_method }}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Ок its fine. But i choose other method

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
public function defaultForUser()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'default_payment_method_id');
}

<h3>Payment methods</h3>
<table border="1">
<tr><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr>
@foreach($user->payment_methods()->withCount('defaultForUser')->get() as $payment_method) 
    <tr>
    <td>
        <div><strong>id:</strong> {{$payment_method->id }}</div>
        <div><strong>gateway id:</strong> {{ $payment_method->braintree_id }}</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        @if($payment_method ->type == PaymentMethod::PAYPAL_ACCOUNT)
            <div><strong>Paypal: </strong> {{$payment_method -> paypal_email}}</div>
        @else
            <div><strong>Card: </strong>{{ $payment_method -> card_brand }} **** **** **** {{$payment_method -> card_last_four}}</div>
        @endif

    <td>
        @if ($payment_method -> default_for_user_count)
            <strong style = "color:green">Default</strong>
        @endif
    </td>
    </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</table>
```